# how to show a tooltip include of thumbnail and excerpt when hovering a post link in other post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

is there any way to call thumbnail and excerpt for link of post in another wordpress post ? for example when i hover a post link in other posts, it shows a tooltip include of thumbnail,excerpt . like this site :http://www.phonearena.com/news/2015-model-year-Toyota-Camry-to-have-wireless-charging-available-as-an-option_id55566

i tried with "https://wordpress.org/plugins/rb-internal-links/" plugin.
in rb-internal-links.php line 114
i add this line to call image :

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

but it not work.

```
<?php

/*

  RB Internal Links
  ==============================================================================

  Link to your other blog posts without having to use the full url, just in case anything changes later on!

  Info for WordPress:
  ==============================================================================
  Plugin Name: RB Internal Links
  Plugin URI: http://www.blograndom.com/blog/
  Description: Link to other blog posts and pages without specifying the full URL. Uses a UI to ease finding the post or page you want to link to.
  Version: 2.0.16
  Text Domain: rb-internal-links
  Author: Arron Woods
  Author URI: http://www.blograndom.com

  Copyright 2009  Arron Woods (blograndom.com)  (email : info@blograndom.com)
  ==============================================================================

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
  (at your option) any later version.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

/**
 * Core class for RB Internal links
 *
 * Sets up hooks, core methods, etc
 */
if (floatval(phpversion()) < 5)
    die('You must have PHP version 5+ to use RB Internal Links');
```

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure I understand your scenario.
If you are looking for a plugin which let you have tooltip with html, image, links, etc
I would suggest tooltipster. Find docs and code here: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i mean in wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

I made a free WordPress plugin after reading augusto's recommendation for using Tooltipster.

[Internal Link Tooltip Preview](https://letswp.justifiedgrid.com/internal-link-tooltip-preview/)